# How to pass props to a component, exported with Store Provider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I want to export my react component along with redux store Provider. So, I wrap the component with this exportWithState callback, but I think I'm not dealing with these props the right way?
**As I'm unable to get props in my component that are passed from the application that is using my component.**

```
export const exportWithState = (Component) => (props) => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Component props />
        </Provider>
    )
}
import {MyComponent} from "./components/my-component";
const MyComponentWithState=exportWithState(MyComponent);
export {MyComponentWithState};
```

Are the props passed from the Application that is using my component should be at the second arrow of callback?

Answer (score 1):

You created a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), try spread the props:

```
export const exportWithState = (Component) => (props) => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Component {...props} />
        </Provider>
    )
}
```

Comment: Ok, let me try that.